# Static linking third party libraries together with my C++ wrapper code

Tags: c++, cuda, linker, static-libraries

I am working on a little project to understand the chain of compiler and linker better.

Suppose that i have the libraries `libfoo.a` and `libbar.a`. I want to create a library `libmy.a`, that acts like a wrapper or top level API to both libraries. The target is, that only `libmy.a` should be required to build an executable, that uses my defined wrapper functions. I created a cmake project and set up the library

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(Wrapper)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)


add_library(my STATIC ${SOME_SRC_FILES})

#set up the lib/inc paths and libs to link
target_include_directories(my PUBLIC /path/to/Foo/inc/ /path/to/Bar/inc/)
target_link_directories(my PUBLIC /path/to/Foo/lib/ /path/to/Bar/lib)
target_link_libraries(my PUBLIC foo bar)
```

That works fine and there is no problem in compilation. However, if I try to reference the object from an external project, it tells me, that I have undefined references to the functions in `libfoo.a` and `libbar.a`. As far as I understand the problem, the linker only creates a declaration in the libmy.a, without including its definition from the external library. I checked this by opening  `libmy.a` with the `nm libmy.a` command, where the used functions of the external libraries are declared, but undefined.

I came across one solution that used `ar` to combine multiple library files. However I would like to avoid such methods, because if it is not a single library, but a bunch of, say 10 libraries, it is not suitable to search each library for a definition and copy it into `libmy.a`. Just throwing all libraries together isn't a solution either, because the file will get too big.

Is it importand to note, that one of these library packages is CUDA?

I am sure there is a solution, but I was not able to find one. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "The target is, that only libmy.a should be required to build an executable" -- That goal goes against the conventional way that *static* libraries are packaged and provided to end users. Static libs *can* be bundled with their dependencies using `ar`, but I think your problem comes from wanting to do this *and* exclude unused object code. That optimization is done by the compiler at the time of building an executable or shared library. End-users should be able to use code from those dependencies too, so they will end up linking it anyways and your library will introduce duplicate definitions.

Comment: @Romen: So the solution would be a shared object, that can work as a standalone library containing all the definitions?

Comment: Yep that's one way to do it. Building a shared object allows you to bundle entire static libs inside with the GCC linker option `--whole-archive` if you want. If you go that way, your end-users need to be aware that your lib includes cuda so they they don't link it again, and whether you *should* include cuda is up to their license.

Comment: @Romen Thank you so much, it worked perfectly. As you pointed out, my misconception was the thought, that static libraries already contain the code of external libraries. But they only keep the reference, so those libraries have to be deployed together, for the user to compile. I was so focused on building a static library, that I didn't think of trying a dynamic library. If you like to, you can post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The target is, that only `libmy.a` should be required to build an executable

This is already an unconventional goal for static libraries.

Static libraries normally only contain the object code built from the source code for *that library*. Users of that library must also link to the libraries that your library requires, because the definitions have not been copied in to your library when it was built.

Tools like `ar` can be used to combine multiple static libraries together, since they are just archives of object code. The tool can not predict which object code the end-user will use though, so it will bundle entire libraries. Otherwise, the end user may be looking for a definition that you left out and then need to link in a 2nd copy of the dependency lib anyways.

If you want to provide a library that has everything the end-user needs, cut down to what your wrapper actually uses, you can build a shared library. Shared libraries are considered executable, so the compiler knows that any unreferenced object code is not going to be used, and it will not be included in the shared library.

You *can* force the entire static libraries to be included in shared libraries though.
On GCC you can use the linker argument: `--whole-archive` to ensure that all of the object code from the following libraries is included.
On MSVC, you can use the `/WHOLEARCHIVE:<library file name>` argument to do the same.